# Can I use the anvil junior kit to upgrade an item that has been enchanted by the Anvil of Krong?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

I'm planning on upgrading my fine steel sword to a katana next level, but meanwhile I've found an Anvil of Krong. Can I still upgrade my sword even if I enchant it first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is **yes**, but the item will lose all of its previous abilities, so in general it's best to save the anvil for the upgraded version.

I've also noticed that when upgrading an item with one ability (set tiles on fire) to an item with another ability (rockburst), I lost both abilities. So be wary about upgrading anvil-enchanted items!